# LINQ Dynamic Expression Call the Count() method on a List property

Tags: c#, linq

Using LINQ Expression dynamic need to call the list Count() method.

```
 public class Foo
 {
      public int Id { get; set; }
 }

 public class Bar
 {
      public ICollection<Foo> Data { get; set; }
 }

 var list = new List<Bar>();
```

Need to build a predicate dynamically which can return me the list of Bar which have Data.Count() > 1 using Expressions.

To start off something like this..

```
MethodInfo method = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods()
.Where(m => m.Name == "Count" && m.GetParameters().Length == 2).Single().MakeGenericMethod(typeof(Bar));
```

Comment: Why do you need to create it dynamically?  All of the information you need is known at compile time; just use a lambda.

Comment: @Servy have a usecase to create it dynamically

Comment: @JonahPereira can you elaborate? What's the reason you couldn't cast the object to IEnumerable<Bar> ?

Comment: @JonahPereira You create things dynamically when there is something that isn't statically known.  So what isn't statically known.  If everything really is all statically known, then you aren't actually doing anything dynamically, you're just unnecessarily creating the expression manually *while still doing it statically*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Count` method you are looking for has only 1 parameter:

```
public static int Count<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
```

You could also use the `Count` property since the source is an `ICollection`:

```
//build a lambda: (Bar bar) => bar.Data.Count > 1;
var barParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof (Bar), "bar");
var barDataProperty = Expression.PropertyOrField(barParam, "Data");
//since Data is of type ICollection, we can use the Count Property
var count = Expression.PropertyOrField(barDataProperty, "Count");
//if you do not want this dependency, call the Count() extension method:
var enumerableCountMethod = typeof (Enumerable).GetMethods()
    .First(method => method.Name == "Count" && method.GetParameters().Length == 1)
    .MakeGenericMethod(typeof(Foo));
var count2 = Expression.Call(enumerableCountMethod, barDataProperty);

var comparison = Expression.GreaterThan(count, Expression.Constant(1));
var comparison2 = Expression.GreaterThan(count2, Expression.Constant(1));

Expression<Func<Bar, bool>> expr = Expression.Lambda<Func<Bar, bool>>(comparison, barParam);
Expression<Func<Bar, bool>> expr2 = Expression.Lambda<Func<Bar, bool>>(comparison2, barParam);

var list = new List<Bar>();
var filteredList = list.Where(expr.Compile());
var filteredList2 = list.Where(expr2.Compile());
```

Answer (score -1):

You could probably use the [predicate builder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx). For example:

```
IQueryable<Product> SearchProducts (params string[] keywords)
{
  var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<Product>();

  foreach (string keyword in keywords)
  {
    string temp = keyword;
    predicate = predicate.Or (p => p.Description.Contains (temp));
  }
  return dataContext.Products.Where (predicate);
}
```