# How to Dynamically create Expression<Func<>> for count and group by clause

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb, predicate, generic-lambda, dynamic-expression

I need to create dynamic lambda expression predicate for below query to query in Cosmos DB.

```
*select City, COUNT(City) as CityCount FROM Cities where status="Active"
group by City*
```

Earlier I have created for equal operation like this

```
var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "t");

MemberExpression expBody = Expression.Property(parameter, columnName);
```

But for getting `Count` and for `Group By` Clause how to do this.

Comment: Are you using EntityFramework? If so it might be worth checking out dynamic linq https://entityframework.net/use-linq-dynamically

Comment: @Jason I'm not sure if the EF Core CosmosDB provider support dynamic linq.

Comment: For `Count` this could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31251571/linq-dynamic-expression-call-the-count-method-on-a-list-property

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with CosmoDB, but wouldn't LINQ be easier for this?

```cs
IQueryable<City> query 
    = cityContainer.GetItemLinqQueryable<City>()
                   .Where(city => city.Status == "Active")
                   .GroupBy(city => city);

using FeedIterator<City> iterator = query.ToFeedIterator<City>();

int cityCount = 0;

for (;iterator.HasMoreResults; cityCount++)
{
    City city = await setIterator.ReadNextAsync();
                    
    // do stuff
}
```

EDIT:

Examples to my answer in the comments ->

```
struct City
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Population { get; set; }
}

IQueryable<City> cities = default;

Func<City, bool> HasNastyName = c => c.Name.Length > 25;
Func<City, bool> IsMassive = c => c.Population > 500;

var nastyNameCities = cities.Where(HasNastyName);
var massiveCities   = cities.Where(IsMassive);
```

Taking the additional option to build these generically into account, you can build predicates quite dynamically with LINQ.
I may be missing what you are trying to do, but I don't see any advantage in the usage of Expression Trees here.

The IQueryProvider<> of CosmoDB is already translating all the Queries for you, so unless I am unaware of something, you are writing unnecessary and possibly less optimized implementations by mapping Expressions to Queries yourself.

Comment: how can we do this using Expression builder as in the project we are using it to create generic predicates.?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what exactly you are doing, but the .Where() method of IQueryable already takes a generic predicate, so if you use this approach instead of building an expression-tree, I assume you already have what you want?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you can use dynamic Linq for this:

---

- https://dynamic-linq.net/
- https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core

There is a GroupBy extension that takes a string:
https://dynamic-linq.net/basic-query-operators#GroupBy

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Dynamic.Core;

namespace ConsoleApp7
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IQueryable<MyOb> testData = new EnumerableQuery<MyOb>(new List<MyOb>());
            var query = testData
                .Where(o => o.Active)
                .GroupBy("City")
                .Select("new (Key as City, Count() as CityCount)");

            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }

    public class MyOb
    {
        public string City { get; set; }
        public bool Active { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The documentation of Dynamic Linq provides this example

```cs
var result = context.Posts.GroupBy("BlogId").Select("new(Key, Count() AS Count)");
```

Comment: I have to use Expression builder as in the code we are using it for creating generic predicates.

Comment: Can you provide an example of how you are using these predicates? Is the idea that you have a sub query in your where clause?

Answer (score 0):

`Count` and `GroupBy` are methods. So you first need to get the corresponding `MethodInfo`s using reflection (take care to get the methods from the `Queryable` class, not `Enumerable`, and the correct overload!).

Then create a method call expression using `Expression.Call(null, methodInfo, queryable)`. (The first parameter should be `null` since both methods are static.) Here, `queryable` is the `IQueryable` you already have built up to this point on which you want to call `Count` or `GroupBy`, respectively. For `GroupBy`, you also need to add an extra parameter, which is the lambda expression for projecting the `City` property - I assume you know how to build that.

---

#### Update

But if I understand your motivation correctly, you are actually trying to dynamically build an `IQueryable` with where-clauses, selects, groupby and/or counts, based on the base `IQueryable` you get from the library, is that correct?

In that case you **shouldn't** express `Count` and `GroupBy` as expressions. Rather, you should dynamically call the *real* methods `Where`, `Select`, `Count` and `GroupBy` on your base `IQueryable` (to get another `IQueryable`), but dynamically build lambda expressions for the parameters of these methods. In the end, you will have an `IQueryable` which the Cosmos DB LINQ provider can evaluate.

Comment: Yes, you got me right. I want to do the same. Will try what you suggested and let you know.

Comment: I tried but not working, can you send me an example of this.